# no scrolling via touch in a box with overflow: scroll / auto in a draggable box

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, draggable, touch-event

I have a problem with a div with overflow scroll / auto box in a second div box which is draggable.
On my desktop PC, I can scroll the inner box without problems on my iPad when trying to scroll the outer box moves.

I use the draggable from jQuery UI library

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3rfjB/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
 <div id="inner">
  A<br/>B<br/>C<br/>D<br/>E<br/>F<br/>G<br/>H
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#outer').draggable();
```

CSS:

```
#outer{
    position: fixed;

    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;

    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;

    border: 1px solid black;
}

#inner{
    position: absolute;

    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;

    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;

    overflow: auto;

    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your advice.

regards
yannic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem:

I have the scroll by touch for the box itself implemented.

```
var TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_X = undefined;
var TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_Y = undefined;

$('#inner').bind('touchstart', function(event){

    TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_X = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_Y = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;

    return false;
});

$('#inner').bind('touchmove', function(event){

    event.srcElement.offsetParent.offsetParent.scrollLeft = event.srcElement.offsetParent.offsetParent.scrollLeft + ( TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_X - event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX );                                                         
    TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_X = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;                                                         

    event.srcElement.offsetParent.offsetParent.scrollTop = event.srcElement.offsetParent.offsetParent.scrollTop + ( TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_Y - event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY );                                                           
    TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_Y = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;

    return false;
});
$('#inner').bind('touchend', function(event){

    TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_X = undefined;
    TOUCH_MOVE_TEST_Y = undefined;

    return false;
});
```

best regards

yannic